# How to remove div in WebView, which appears dynamically? (Android)

Tags: android, webview

I have a `WebView` in my `Android` app, I want to remove `div` which appears dynamically in this WebView.

There is a text input, where user can type the text, if user types more than 2000 symbols, there is appear `div`, which says that user inserted more than 2000 symbols, I want to remove it.

In order to remove static elements, I'm injecting `JavaScript`, and it works as expected, however, with dynamic elements it doesn't work.

Here the code which I have, I'm calling it inside onCreate method:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
                view.loadUrl("javascript:getValue()");
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                "document.getElementsByClassName('footer')[0].style.display='none'+ 
                "document.getElementsByClassName('extra_information')[0].style.display='none';"+"})()" );` 
                }
            });
            webView.loadUrl("https://somewebsite");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**document.getElementsByClassName**-- it returns an array of all child elements which have any of the given class names.

In your `Webview`: Use Bind() to listen for Dom updates

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView web, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        web.loadUrl("jquery:(function() { " +
             $(\".extra_information\").bind(\"DOMSubtreeModified\", function() {
                document.getElementsByClassName('extra_information')[0].style.display='none';
             });+"})()" );
         }
    });
```

Here is a sample [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eQErD/1/)

Comment: I know exactly name of that "div" which I want to remove, let's call it "extra_informatiom", and when url first loaded this div doesn't appears, because user hasn't typed anything yet, but when this div appears, after user typed 2000 symbols, it's not removed from the screen, probably because webView.loadUrl is executed only once in the beginning of the loading url

Comment: I have updated the answer. You can listen for DOm changes event in your function.

Comment: I just have tried to test this approach, it seems that something wrong with quotes, I got: "Cannot resolve the method " for $, function and document.

Comment: try escaping the quotes. Also make sure Jquery in loaded in webview.